# Append three json file into one json file

Tags: android, json

***Aim:-*** I have to merge 3 json files into 1 json file.I need to append text to the output file after removing last character from the output file.

***NOTE:-*** I have done this to merge 3 json files into 1 json file.I want to append text into the output file.This code appends text but does not remove the  last }.Can anyone help me with the code.Thank You in advance and have a good day in advance.

I have a record of json objects for name,email,lat,lon,date.This fields are in different json files.I have merged them into 1 json file.This job is accomplished.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:-** when i append the next record i want the json file to look like

```
{Record:[{"name1","val","date1","val","lat1","val"..}],[{"name2","val","date2","val","lat2","val"...}]}
```

**OUTPUT ACHIEVED:-**

```
{Record:[{"name1","val","date1","val","lat1","val"..}],{Record:[{"name2","val","date2","val","lat2","val"...}]}
```

**Code:-**

```
 static class CopyFileContent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(); //get access to directory path
        File myDir = new File(root + "/GeoPark");//create folder in internal storage
        myDir.mkdirs();// make directory
        File destFile = new File(myDir, FILENAME11);//making a new file in the folder
    /* Source file, from which content will be copied */
        File sourceFile1 = new File(myDir, FILENAME12);
        File sourceFile2 = new File(myDir, FILENAME13);
        File sourceFile3 = new File(myDir, FILENAME14);

    /* destination file, where the content to be pasted */
        // File destFile = new File(FILENAME);

    /* if file not exist then create one */
        if (!destFile.exists()) {
            try {
                destFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        InputStream input1 = null;
        InputStream input2 = null;
        InputStream input3 = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        InputStream input4 = null;

        try {

            /* FileInputStream to read streams */
            input1 = new FileInputStream(sourceFile1);
            input2 = new FileInputStream(sourceFile2);
            input3 = new FileInputStream(sourceFile3);

        /* FileOutputStream to write streams */
            output = new FileOutputStream(destFile, true);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            output.write("{Record:[{".getBytes());
            while ((bytesRead = input1.read(buf)) > 0) {
                output.write(buf, 1, bytesRead);

                RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(destFile, "rw");
                long length = f.length() - 2;
                f.setLength(length);
                length = f.length();
                f.close();
                output.write(",".getBytes());

            }

            while ((bytesRead = input2.read(buf)) > 0) {
                output.write(buf, 1, bytesRead);
                RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(destFile, "rw");
                long length = f.length() - 2;
                f.setLength(length);
                length = f.length();
                f.close();
                output.write(",".getBytes());

            }

            while ((bytesRead = input3.read(buf)) > 0) {
                output.write(buf, 1, bytesRead);
                RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(destFile, "rw");
                long length = f.length() - 2;
                f.setLength(length);
                length = f.length();
                f.close();
                output.write(",".getBytes());
                output.write(b.getBytes());
                output.write(d.getBytes());
                output.write("}]}".getBytes());
                RandomAccessFile f1=new RandomAccessFile(destFile,"rw");
                long length1= f1.length()-1;
                f1.setLength(length1);
                f1.close();

                output.write(",".getBytes());
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {

                if (null != input1) {
                    input1.close();
                }

                if (null != input2) {
                    input2.close();
                }

                if (null != input3) {
                    input3.close();
                }

                if (null != output) {
                    output.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: if all three files contains only JSON, you can read file and convert the string into JSON. add last two json into first and write it back to file.

Comment: @Prashant I need to merge 3 json files into 1.I have accomplished this task.I need to append text to the output file by removing the last character.

Comment: You can use the below mentioned Library to get data / parse data from Json in String Values then create a New Json with that data...  https://github.com/afollestad/ason/

Comment: @DarShan I dont need to parse data.I need to append text by removing last charcter.Please refer my code once.

Comment: @Manu the above mentioned library will probably help you do that... check its ReadMe

Comment: @DarShan I am using RandomFileAccess to erase last character.Can you help me accomplish the task with this.

Comment: Please check my edited version

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you need a deep merge, merge the contents of fields with identical names (just like when copying folders in Windows). This function may be helpful:

```
/**
 * Merge "source" into "target". If fields have equal name, merge them recursively.
 * @return the merged object (target).
 */
public static JSONObject deepMerge(JSONObject source, JSONObject target) throws JSONException {
    for (String key: JSONObject.getNames(source)) {
            Object value = source.get(key);
            if (!target.has(key)) {
                // new value for "key":
                target.put(key, value);
            } else {
                // existing value for "key" - recursively deep merge:
                if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject valueJson = (JSONObject)value;
                    deepMerge(valueJson, target.getJSONObject(key));
                } else {
                    target.put(key, value);
                }
            }
    }
    return target;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject a = new JSONObject("{offer: {issue1: value1}, accept: true}");
    JSONObject b = new JSONObject("{offer: {issue2: value2}, reject: false}");
    System.out.println(a+ " + " + b+" = "+JsonUtils.deepMerge(a,b));

}
```

If you want to merge them, so e.g. a top level object has 4 keys (key1, Key2, Key3, Key4), I think you have to do that manually:

```
JSONObject merged = new JSONObject(Obj1, JSONObject.getNames(Obj1));
for(String key : JSONObject.getNames(Obj2))
{
  merged.put(key, Obj2.get(key));
}
```

Comment: i dont want same fields to merge

Comment: ok, it's simple. you can check for same fields and ignore them